# Travailler avec ou avec des ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, articles

Quelle est la formulation correcte ?

> J'ai travaillé avec des ingénieurs français.

ou

> J'ai travaillé avec ingénieurs français.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La bonne formulation est :

> J'ai travaillé avec des ingénieurs français.

Dans cet exemple, on ne peut pas omettre « des ».

Comment: Tu dis ça *avec certitude*…

Comment: :P Voilà, édité et enlevé les niaiseries qui s'y trouvaient.